# how to select the auto popup hotel names in a hotel booking site in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit4, browser-automation

I am working on automating the following hotel booking site. I need to select the auto popup hotel name once I type the hotel in the first search box...I don't know how to do this.

I have navigated through the link and clicked Demo, then clicked the first link that appeared on the page.
I tried to click on the first search box and I need to enter a hotel from the auto popup list...I don't know how to do this because this has no PAC-item...
https://www.phptravels.net/home

```
public class Question1 {
    WebDriver Driver = null;
     WebDriverWait wait = null;
     String url = "https://phptravels.com/demo/";
    
     
     @BeforeTest
      public void beforeTest() {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","src\\test\\resources\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
         ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
         options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Arrays.asList("disable-popup-blocking"));
         options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
         
         Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
         Driver.manage().window().maximize();
         Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 25);

            
             String winHandle = Driver.getWindowHandle();
            //Driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
             //new WebDriverWait(Driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[title='webpush-onsite']")));
             //new WebDriverWait(Driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button#deny.button.close"))).click();
      }
    
    @Test
  public void f() {
        Driver.get(url);
         System.out.println("*****In the main page*****");
        String xpathDemo = "//*[@id=\"mega-nav-navigation\"]/div/ul[1]/li[2]/a";
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathDemo)).click();
        String Title = "PHPTRAVELS | Travel Technology Partner";
        /*try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"PopupSignupForm_0\"]/div[2]/div[1]")));
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"PopupSignupForm_0\"]/div[2]/div[1]")).click();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No popup..."+ e.getMessage());
        }
        */
        String username = Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Main\"]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div")).getAttribute("innerText");
        username = username.substring(6) ;
        String password = username.substring(30);
        System.out.println("Username text :"+username + "\npassword is:"+password);
        
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Main\"]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/a")).click();
        utils.HelperFunctions2.switchToWindow(Driver, Title);
        
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"s2id_autogen16\"]")).click();
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/ul")).click();
        
        
  }
  
  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
      Driver.quit();
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is **Demo** on the webpage `https://www.phptravels.net/home`

Comment: @DebanjanB - I found the 'Demo' in the menu here on https://phptravels.com/ page.

Comment: @SwaroopHumane Yep, it shows up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already built bots, auto image pickers and more and I have never used the By.xpath method. Classname is much easier to use!

```
public void f(){
Driver.get(url);
String getInputFocusId = "select2-input";
Driver.findElement(By.className(getInputFocusId).click();
//now focused!
String text = Driver.findElement(By.className("select2-match").getText();
//text is the first default search match of the list.
}
```

There is also a more complicated way.
In Selenium you can sendKeys to an Element.

If the input element is focused the first match is also focused.
By clicking on Enter the focused match will be searched and displayed in the input element.
Finally you have to read the data from the input Element!

```
public void f(){
Driver.get(url);
String getInputFocusId = "select2-input";
WebElement element = Driver.findElement(By.className(getInputFocusId);
element.click();
//element.sendKeys(Key.DOWN);
element.sendKeys(Key.ENTER);
String text = element.getText();
//this is the text of the first search match
//if you want to get the second or third just repeat sending the DOWN key.
    }
```

IMPORTANT: Make sure to run each line delayed (200ms is a good time). This helps you finding errors... For example in the Instagram Auth Process I delayed a lot of lines, and it finally worked!

I hope my answer helps you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Below xpath is result of 1st hotel, changing the index it will intreact with rest of the elements.

After filing text to the hotel text box.
give Thread.sleep(2000);
use below xpath. I hope it will work

```
(.//ul[@class='select2-results']/following::div[@class='select2-result-label'])[2]
```

Comment: Thanks .. its usefull